# How to draw a vertical line on a CubicLineChart?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm displaying a beautiful chart that has two XYSeries in it. Each series has 24 values that are plotted at X-positions 0 thru 23. One series shows the temperature over a 24 hour period, the other series shows the precipitation probability over the same 24 hour period.

The problem comes when I try adding a third series for drawing a single vertical line (used as a "cursor", along with an `OnTouchListener`). The idea is to draw a 2-datapoint series which would render as a single vertical line which I can use for my cursor.

I tried this:

```
XYSeries cursorLine = new XYSeries("", 2);
cursorLine.add(5, 0);
cursorLine.add(5, 100);
dataset.addSeries(cursorLine);
```

That doesn't display anything though.

I also tried using two very close X values as suggested by ACE's Dan in [this Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/achartengine/nB135l6qvA0):

```
XYSeries cursorLine = new XYSeries("", 2);
cursorLine.add(5.00000, 0);
cursorLine.add(5.00001, 100);
dataset.addSeries(cursorLine);
```

Unfortunately, this stretches the "cursor" line across the entire width of the chart, like it's assuming it's made up of 24 data points rather than just the 2 I've specified. Example:

[image]

I also tried adding 24 data points, 23 that have a Y value of 0 and only one (at X position 5) having a Y value of 100. Because this is a CUBIC line chart, my cursor shows up with "heels" on its bottom; the cursor on the other 23 points are also visible at the bottom of the chart. Example:

[image: Shows heels of cursor line]

I tried setting the adjacent data points to an X value of +/- 0.00001, but that does not remove the heels -- that's about as small as they get regardless of how close to the cursor position horizontally I set them.

I've been playing with this for the last hour or so, but I can't get a simple vertical line shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using scale = 2 for the vertical line series. Each scale computes the visible data range and tries to fit the data such as it displays entirely. I suggest you add your vertical line data to a scale that already exists.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks Dan! Although the bigger problem I'm having seems to be that in order for the touch event to be received by my listener, the user must touch the actual line on the chart; touching any other part (such as the background) won't fire the event. I'm thinking of enclosing the GraphicalView in a FrameLayout and listening for touch events on that instead, passing coordinate info to the chart to draw the cursor line; what are your thoughts there? Is there another way to receive all touch events on the chart's canvas rather than just those on the lines therein? Thanks again!

Comment: Just did, got the events to pass thru. That apparently isn't the problem; the problem is when I pass in the MotionEvent.getX() and MotionEvent.getY() values to AbstractChart.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(point). That method will only return a SeriesSelection if the point it receives is "near" a line. Any ideas on how--given an x-position--I can convert that to my X values (the 24 hours)? I'll keep looking at the code, maybe there's something obvious.

Comment: I'm going to post a new question as the original issue has been fixed, and having this separate issue categorically as a separate question will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out something that sort of works, in that it shows what appears to be a straight vertical line. It feels really, really dirty to do, but here's the code:

```
double x = 5;

for(double i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    if(i != x)
    {
        cursorLine.add(i, -100);
    }
    else
    {
        cursorLine.add(x - 0.000001, -100);
        cursorLine.add(x, 200);
        cursorLine.add(x + 0.000001, -100);
    }
}
```

`x` can be set to whatever X-position at which to draw the cursor.

Basically, what I'm doing is drawing the bottom and top of the line so far off the graph that the part that is visible is the straight part. So this still has the "heels" at the bottom, etc. But since I don't allow zooming or panning, these things are hidden therefore it works well enough.

It'd be great if someone has a better solution to this though. I'm going to go take a cold shower...